# Xtend sorting using ECollections

Tags: java, eclipse, sorting, xtend

I am trying to sort an EList of functions by using Java's Comparator, but the list is not sorted after calling sort().

The way I implement it is this:

```
//Func.xtend <-- Start -->

public class NameComparator implements Comparator<Function_Name> {  
    override int compare (Function_Name function1, Function_Name function2)
    {
        return function1.func.compareToIgnoreCase(function2.func)
    }
}

public class CheckNames {   
    def void checkDuplicateNames(Main_func para_func) {
        var EList<Function_Name> functions = para_func.getContains()        
        var NameComparator pc = new NameComparator()

        functions.sort(pc) //<-- sorting here

        var Iterator<Function_Name> oIt = functions.iterator ()
        while (oIt.hasNext)
        {           
            var Function_Name func = oIt.next   ()
            System::out.println(func.func.toString)
        }
    }
}

// <-- End -->
```

Am I doing something wrong? Theoretically, after calling functions.sort(pc), the contents in variable "functions" should already be sorted, right? Or do I still need to do some processing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, `List::sort` in Xtend doesn't sort in-place, but returns a new sorted list. So you have to call `List::sortInPlace` instead.

Apart from this, you might run into problems when you try to sort *unique* ELists (for example, containments) in-place. During the sort operation (Xtend actually calls `java.util.Collections.sort` for this), some elements may temporarily be contained twice in the list. However, unique lists check for duplicates and throw an `IllegalArgumentException` when you try to add an element a second time (see `AbstractEList.set(in, E)`). To avoid this, you should sort unique ELists like this:

```
var sortedFunctions = functions.sort(pc)
functions.clear()
functions.addAll(sortedFunctions)
```